# Garage door needs a push or pull to start opening/closing

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have some 20+ year old garage door openers, and one works great, the other will sometimes open/close fine.

Sometimes when I hit the switch there is a click and a buzz like the motor is trying to lift, but the door does not move.  If I hit the switch again it stops.  If I go over to the door and pull it up about an inch (or pull it down, if it's open) the motor "catches" and it goes up/down just fine.

Is there a slack adjustment of some sort I can look at, or is the motor bad?  I replaced the capacitor on the door that is not working about 6 months ago, and have replaced the springs and safety cables on both doors at about the same time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you cleaned and lubricated things recently?

Comment: if your springs have broke or need additional tension this can cause a opener to stall also.

Comment: Electrolytic starter capacitor on the motor? Those die over time.

Comment: Isn't that the same tihng I mention in the third paragraph?  **I replaced the capacitor on the door that is not working about 6 months ago**

Answer (score 1):

Though they're 20+ years old, they didn't miss the plastic bug. It's likely that your drive sprocket on the one is worn down & begin to miss. However, a little more specific & much less involved to remedy to your symptoms would be to play with the up-force & down-force adjustments.

Usually, clockwise is to ramp up & counterclockwise is to ramp down. The openers develop flat spots on the clutch & screwing-in or clockwise reseats the contact points. If it works it'll work for years, I'm going on 5-years now with my current one & two others I had before got 8 & 10 more years before adjustments didn't work anymore.

Comment: OK, I can try that, I assume the adjustment will be fairly obvious when I take the cover off then?

Comment: Yep, give it a shot & depending on the unit it may just be right on the back with fairly clear markings. Nothing to remove, but you still might need a small flathead screwdriver to twist them if they're recessed.

Comment: At most, you probably only have to remove the light cover.

Answer (score 1):

I'd focus first on the **mechanical condition of the doors**.  I have some huge industrial doors (drive-through for semi's) with enormous power openers.  They were very distressed from 40 years of abuse, I overhauled them.  With such burly openers, I assumed it would be humanly impossible to open the doors by hand.  Nope! They threw open easily. And then I realized: they only needed the power openers becuase the doors had problems!

And then I realized: forcing doors with problems **can kill you**.

The openers only concealed the increasingly dangerous condition of the doors.  Needless to say, I did not reconnect the openers.

So my suggestion is to disconnect the power drives on both doors and use them by hand.  Let your sense of touch tell you whether the doors are working smoothly.  Fix, or have fixed, if necessary.  Doors have powerful springs that can maim and kill.

Then address any opener issues.